# Can't manange to build Rtmpdump with KSV Patch

Tags: compiling, gcc

I'm trying to build rtmpdump with KSV patch

```
git clone https://github.com/chopraaa/rtmpdump-ksv.git
cd rtmpdump-ksv
patch -p0 -i Patch.diff
make
```

Patch is OK but then i have errors

```
root@ubuntu:~/rtmpdump-ksv-master# make
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/rtmpdump-ksv-master/librtmp'
gcc -Wall   -DRTMPDUMP_VERSION=\"v2.4\" -DUSE_OPENSSL  -O2 -fPIC   -c -o     rtmp.o                                                                                                                                                                  rtmp.c
In file included from handshake.h:86:0,
                 from rtmp.c:161:
dh.h: In function ‘DHInit’:
dh.h:256:12: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘DH {aka     struct dh_                                                                                                                                                                 st}’
   MP_new(dh->g);
            ^
dh.h:171:19: note: in definition of macro ‘MP_new’
 #define MP_new(m) m = BN_new()
                   ^
In file included from rtmp.c:161:0:
handshake.h: In function ‘InitRC4Encryption’:
handshake.h:120:12: error: storage size of ‘ctx’ isn’t known
   HMAC_CTX ctx;
            ^~~
<builtin>: recipe for target 'rtmp.o' failed
make[1]: *** [rtmp.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/rtmpdump-ksv-master/librtmp'
Makefile:76: recipe for target 'librtmp/librtmp.a' failed
make: *** [librtmp/librtmp.a] Error 2
```

I dont know how to fix it 
                                   ^
handshake.h:125:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘HMAC_setup’
   HMAC_setup(ctx, secretKey, 128);